# Контроль веб-приложением количества открытых сессий

Tags: http, сессия

Какие есть способы у веб-приложения узнать, что одна копия приложения уже открыта на данном компьютере? Пробовал открывать сайт с двух разных браузеров - все равно определяет вторую сессию. Пробовал настраивать прокси на одном из браузеров - приложение все равно ругается на вторую сессию.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если запустить один браузер без прокси и другой браузер с проксей — ругается на две сессии? А если предварительно почистить историю и куки и повторить?

Comment: @andreymal : Правильно. Попробовал, не помогает.